# simple_form map check_boxes collection to integer mask

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I want to extend registration form in one Rails app for users to be able to submit their roles.

It basically adds few check boxes in the form.
I'm using simple_form gem and it looks like this:

```
    = f.input :role_mask, as: :check_boxes, label: false,
        collection: ['Investor', 'Mentor', 'Developer', 'Other']
```

To keep this information in database, I added `role_mask:integer` field to the User model.

So if the user checked, say, `Mentor` and `Developer`, it should store `6` in `role_mask` field (its mask = 0110).

I know, this mapping could be done inside controller, but since I'm contributing to this app, I don't want to touch controller. So I'm wondering does simple_form provide some tools to solve this or I should use JavaScript to do the mapping? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. If you don't want to do it in the controller you will have to do it client side. There is no way to simple_form generate the javascript, so you will have to do it yourself.